# spyder-kernel module missing after switching from Python 3.9 to 3.8 in Spyder5

Tags: python, spyder

I installed Anaconda and Spyder to run a python code with Python 3.9. Then I download Python 3.8 to try this code. However, after switching from 3.9 to 3.8, spyder-kernel module cannot be found.
I feel it's because the setting of Python 3.8, however, have no idea how to fix it. Thanks.

[image: Python 3.9 is used in Conda]

[image: Spyder-kernels module missing after switching to python 3.8]

[image: Python 3.8 is used here, but not in conda]

Comment: Looks like the 3.8 installation doesn’t have the spyder kernel installed; as stated.  Did you try the suggestion shown in the error message to install the kernel?  I’ve seen this a few times and that fixes it every time.

Comment: Aside, why (specifically) install 3.8 when you have 3.9 already installed?

Comment: @S3DEV Thanks. I did use those two command to install kernal, but it doesn't work. Really odd. For python version, it's just a try. Sorry for the late response, I'm offline for the past days

Comment: Check the kernel installed to the ‘correct’ / intended Python installation / environment.  When using `pip` verify *which* `pip` is being used to install.  If on a Unix-like system, use `which pip` to verify the kernel will be installed to the intended Python installation, (i.e. Python 3.8).

Comment: I am having this same problem. I created a virtual env using conda 4.11.0, python 3.9.7, and spyder 5.1.5. I confirmed that spyder-kernels version 2.1.3 is installed in my environment, but I still received this error. I tried re-creating the environment from scratch, and forcing a re-install of spyder-kernel.

Comment: I also tried rolling back to Spyder 5.0.5 on Python 3.9, and I tried rolling back to Python 3.8. In both cases the spyder-kernel error was displayed even though it is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Check which kernel your Spyder interpreter is pointed towards. Even though I was doing a clean install of Spyder, it turns out the interpreter was pointed to a different environment that did not include Spyder-Kernels. Once you change the Python Interpreter back to the default, close the console and Spyder will create a new console using the default interpreter in the expected environment.

[image: Change the Python Interpreter to default]